# Indexing random Dice Rolls (VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, indexing

I am building a simulation for the game of craps, below is my code to run through the process of rolling, along with a dice Class that executes the random rolls. I want to be able to graph the distribution of the rolls. For that, I believe I need to but the random rolls into an array, can anyone help I have been stuck for awhile.

```
Sub SetThePoint()
    Dim lngRoll As Long
    Dim lngNextRoll As Long
    Dim lngThePoint As Long
    Dim lngCounter As Long
    Dim boolPointSet As Boolean
    Dim boolResolved As Boolean

    Set objDiceDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set objDice = New clsDice
    'this procedure takes the value the roll dice function and conintiously rolls until a point is set
'StartGame:
    Do
        objDice.RollDice
        lngRoll = objDice.sumDice
        'Debug.Print lngRoll
        Select Case lngRoll
            Case Is = 2
                boolPointSet = False
            Case Is = 3
                boolPointSet = False
            Case Is = 4
                boolPointSet = True
                lngThePoint = 4
            Case Is = 5
                boolPointSet = True
                lngThePoint = 5
            Case Is = 6
                boolPointSet = True
                lngThePoint = 6
            Case Is = 7
                boolPointSet = False
            Case Is = 8
                boolPointSet = True
                lngThePoint = 8
            Case Is = 9
                boolPointSet = True
                lngThePoint = 9
            Case Is = 10
                boolPointSet = True
                lngThePoint = 10
            Case Is = 11
                boolPointSet = False
            Case Is = 12
                boolPointSet = False
            Case Else
                boolPointSet = False
        End Select
        'Call PassLineBet(lngRoll)
    Loop While boolPointSet = False


    If boolPointSet = True Then
        Do Until boolResolved = True
            Debug.Print "The current point is a " & lngThePoint
            objDice.RollDice
            lngNextRoll = objDice.sumDice
            'Debug.Print lngCounter
            Debug.Print "You Rolled a " & lngNextRoll
                If lngNextRoll = lngThePoint Then
                    'boolResolved = True
                    Debug.Print "You win"
                    GoTo StartGame:
                ElseIf lngNextRoll = 7 Then
                    boolResolved = True
                    Debug.Print "You Lose"
                    'Debug.Print "Roll #: " & lngCounter
                    Exit Sub
                Else
                    boolResolved = False
                End If
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Break, Class:

```
Option Explicit
Public diceOne As Long
Public diceTwo As Long
Public rollNum As Long
Public lngRollCounter As Long
Public sumDice As Long
Public lngPointsMade As Long
Public lSum As Long



Public Sub RollDice()
    lngRollCounter = Counter
    diceOne = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)
    diceTwo = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 6)
    sumDice = diceOne + diceTwo
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
End Sub
Public Function Counter() As Long
    Dim i As Long

    i = i + 1
    Counter = i


End Function
```

Comment: Possibly completely unrelated to your question but your `Counter` function will always return `1`.  (You create a variable called `i`, which is implicitly initialised to zero.  You then add `1` to that variable, and then return that incremented value.)  Is that intentional?

Comment: Your code is somehow confusing and missing. You need to declare `Dim objDiceDict As Object`. What is `clsDice`? Where is this object? `GoTo StartGame:` statement does not work like that. As YowE3K stated, you need to declare `Dim i As Long` outside of your sub if you want to increment it. I stopped looking at your code after all of these.

Comment: The structure you use to store the data depends one how you want to use it. If you want to create a graph that shows how many times each of the numbers 1 through 6 were rolled, regardless of order, than an array with dimensions 1 to 6 would work, and you add one to the array element for each die roll result. You could use the same technique for rolls of 2 through 12 (using total of two dice). If you want to include a "time" element you could use a collection to store each roll, you could add objDice to the collection after each rollDice.